# What is the issue here when I try to deploy my rails app?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku

This is the error I get when I deploy locally using 'rails s'

```
couldn't find file 'grayscale-sass/assets/bower_components/jquery.easing/js/jquery.easing.js' with type 'application/javascript'
Extracted source (around line #20):
20 //= require grayscale-sass/assets/bower_components/jquery.easing/js/jquery.easing.js
```

Here is my application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .


//= require grayscale-sass/assets/bower_components/jquery.easing    /js/jquery.easing.js


//= require grayscale-sass/assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
//= require grayscale-sass/assets/js/grayscale.js
```

However if I go into my application.js file and delete the '//=' in front of require jquery, the error goes away and my application runs. However, when I deploy to heroku it fails and comes up with an error that says

```
ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: name (jquery) (line: 14, col: 8, pos: 586)
```

Where line 14 would be my application.js file of 
     require jquery

Comment: How are you calling it in your file, the path it is looking for looks odd to me, can you post the line calling it in you file?

Answer (score 0):

Rails' assets compiler (ie Sprockets) can't find that file. The error goes away when you delete the //= because it stops looking for it while compiling the asset. This means you end up with actual JavaScript that contains the line "require ...", which is invalid JavaScript and not what you want (`require=` is a Rails/Sprocket thing, not a JavaScript thing).

To fix this, you'll need to put the file in the right place. For a third-party library like grayscale-sass, the standard way is to copy it to `your-project/vendor/assets/&hellip;`. That said, there are better ways to pull third-party front-end projects into Rails. [Rails Assets](https://rails-assets.org/) is good for this.